# How to find $x$ such that $f(x)$ takes a prescribed value

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions

Find $x$ such that 
\begin{equation}
x\tanh(x\sqrt{2\alpha})=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\alpha}}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is equivalent to
$$x\sqrt{2\alpha}\tanh(x\sqrt{2\alpha})=2$$
so your question boils down to solving
$$t\tanh(t)=2.$$
This I believe cannot be solved analytically, but you approximately have $t \approx \pm 2.07 \approx 2$, whence $x \approx \pm 2.07/\sqrt{2\alpha} \approx \sqrt{2/\alpha}$.

Comment: Thank you, that is all I needed

Comment: Okay, no problem!